# How to make ReactNative stacktrace/error message more readable

Tags: react-native

I've tried to test a development using ReactNative, then I tried to add `<br/>` (as it's an invalid component) inside a `<Text>` component, it shows something like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of null
at launchEditor (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/launchEditor.js:153:29)
at Object.handle (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/openStackFrameInEditorMiddleware.js:17:7)
at next (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at Object.handle (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:74:7)
at next (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at Object.handle (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:74:7)
at next (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at Object.compression [as handle] (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/compression/index.js:205:5)
at next (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/loadRawBodyMiddleware.js:20:5)
```

And on the device:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to make it easier to read the error (which line are the problem)?

Comment: Got a similar issue. Seems like some internal react error with the cli

Comment: What version of react-native-cli do you have installed ?

Comment: @seba.wagner react-native-cli: 1.3.0

Comment: oh for us it had to do with some dependency problem. But basically there is a react-native-cli-2.0.0, you should really get that one and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You should define REACT_EDITOR environment variable to allow RN to run your favorite text editor. The simplest way is to run something like `env REACT_EDITOR=atom npm start`. Or you can set this variable permanently, just google [how to set environment variable on ${OS}](http://www.google.com/?q=how+to+set+environment+variable+on+%24%7BOS%7D)